# Facebook Ads API image use my CDN url

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm working with the `Facebook Ads API`, and i'd like to know if is there possible to they deliver the image from my CDN not theirs; or is it only possible in the FBx RTB?

Comment: Why? And I'm pretty sure it is not possible

Comment: I wan't to create the images dynamically to use for Retargeting/Remarketing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have ad images served directly to users from your own server unless the ads are using FBX - even with that option where each impression can be bid for with a custom image, the image associated with the ad impression is cached by Facebook and served from Facebook's CDN and not directly from the advertiser's system